# JBoss FUSE hibernate application giving "waiting for unsatisfied dependencies" error

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jbossfuse

I am developing sample application to demonstrate hibernate capabilities with FUSE. I was able to installed required dependencies and install my project in to FUSE. But unfortunately I was not getting any error but when I list the installed applications it shows my application waiting. As show in below screen.

[image]

Once I check on the log it's show following message.

```
OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=cameloneeac, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml) is waiting for unsatisfied dependencies
[[&org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean&#35;0]]
```

Then after some time in log I can see this kind of error message.

```
Unable to create application context for [cameloneeac], unsatisfied dependencies: Dependency on [(objectClass=com.vcc.camelone.commonsdomain.model.dao.CoreCodeCountryDao)] (from bean [&org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.OsgiServiceProxyFactoryBean&#35;0])
```

Does anyone experienced this kind of error when working on the FUSE with hibernate ? Please be kind enough to provide some clue to resolve this issue .

Comment: Can you share the code where you try to inject bean

Comment: Is `com.vcc.camelone.commonsdomain.model.dao` package exported from your bundle?